# how to convert video in format 1:1 and 9:16 using ffmpeg in android?

Tags: android

I have used the below command.

```
strings = new String[]{"-y", "-i", tempOriginalVideoPath, "-r", "15", "-aspect", "1:1", "-strict", "-2", tempEditVideoPath}
```

it's not working default system camera recorded video.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the FFmpeg library (http://Writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java)
- The command needs to be splitted using .split(" ");

  final String[] cmd = "-i /storage/emulated/0/Your.mp4 -vf crop=640:256:0:400 -threads 5 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 /storage/emulated/0/YourCroppedMovie.mp4".split(" ");

Example use -vf crop=1080:1080:0:0 to crop the video to a square. (Without messing up the ratio)

Hope it helps you

Comment: The question was to change the Aspect Ratio of the application. How to do that ? can you still guide us ?